# Accessing localhost Webserver Over Network

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

I am using my local machine as a development server. I have my hosts file set up as such:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   cdog24
127.0.0.1   xxxxxorg
127.0.0.1   newintranet
```

My httpd-vhosts.conf file is set up as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\Webserver\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\Webserver\htdocs\cdog24"
    ServerName cdog24
    ServerAlias cdog24
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\Webserver\htdocs\xxxxxorg"
    ServerName xxxxxorg
    ServerAlias xxxxxorg
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\Webserver\htdocs\newintranet"
    ServerName newintranet
    ServerAlias newintranet
</VirtualHost>
```

I am running xampp and can access each site on my local machine respectively by typing in:

http://localhost
http://cdog24
http://xxxxxorg
http://newintranet

When i go to a different computer on my network, I assume I have to type int he name of my machine or use the IP address. So, when I type in the following:

http://machinename/cdog24 or http://10.1.0.24/newintranet

I am taken to a 404 page.

What am I missing? Firewall on local machine or network do not factor as they are both off. I am on a Windows 7 local machine, the remote machine is also Windows 7.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to edit the hosts file on the remote machine (where the browser is running, not the server):

```
x.x.x.x   cdog24
x.x.x.x   xxxxxorg
x.x.x.x   newintranet
```

Change x.x.x.x to the IP address of the Windows box that is running the server.

Now you should be able to browse to, say http://cdog24/ in your browser.

However, do NOT add a localhost entry that points to the other machine.  localhost should always point to 127.0.0.1!

Comment: This one solved it. Adding my IP address to the remote machines host file did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to work out what the IP address of your machine is on your network, and then edit teh hosts files on the other machines to point to yours

```
<your local IP>   cdog24
<your local IP>   xxxxxorg
<your local IP>   newintranet
```

You maybe also have to update the apache conf file to work from your network address rather than 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with just http://machinename/ ? 
http://machinename/directory would require that the document root be pointing to htdocs itself.